# How to remain in the selected toggle button/page after reloading the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, togglebutton

I have the following working code and have the menu-1/content-1 as the default when first opening or reloading the page. However, I would like to know if there is a way of after reloading the browser remaining in the selected menu/content, i.e. if for instances I clicked on menu-2 and I reload my browser, I would still be on menu-2 and the same if I selected any other.

Would this be possible?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

P.S.: Here's my **CodePen** in case you find it easier:
https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/vYYaRzN

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // only show menu-1
  $('.menu-1').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-2, .menu-3').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-2, .menu-3').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-2, .content-3').removeClass('active');
    }
    
    $('.menu-1').addClass('active');
    $('.content-1').addClass('active'); 
  });
  
  // only show menu-2
    $('.menu-2').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-1, .menu-3').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-1, .menu-3').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-1, .content-3').removeClass('active');
    }
    
    $('.menu-2').addClass('active');
    $('.content-2').addClass('active'); 
  });
  
  // only show menu-3
    $('.menu-3').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-2, .menu-1').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-2, .menu-1').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-2, .content-1').removeClass('active');
    }
    
    $('.menu-3').addClass('active');
    $('.content-3').addClass('active'); 
  });  
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 90vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  position: relative;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bottom-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-grey-dark-3);
  z-index: 50;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
      > a {
      display: block;
      color: green;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 0 10px;

      &.active {
        color: black;
      }
    }
}

.menu-1.active,
.menu-2.active,
.menu-3.active {
  color: black;
}

.content-1,
.content-2,
.content-3 {
  display: none;
}

.content-1.active,
.content-2.active,
.content-3.active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>My header</header>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-1 active">House content</div>
    <div class="content-2">Map content</div>
    <div class="content-3">Explore content</div>
  <div class="bottom-navbar">
    <a href="#" class="menu-1 active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-2"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-3"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As recommended, I tried the URL# and reduced the amount of repetition. So far I am close to achieving the result I desire but not there yet. The following code shows an empty content when I click on any of the menu icons. However, when I do reload the page it does show the content of the menu I was in. This is the progress so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a[class^=menu]").click(function() {
    if ($("a[class^=menu],div[class^=content]").hasClass("active")) {

      $("a[class^=menu],div[class^=content]").removeClass("active");

      var href = $(this).attr("href");

      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(href).addClass("active");
    }
  });

  if (window.location.hash.substr(1) != "") {
    $("a[class^=menu],div[class^=content]").removeClass("active");
    $('a[href="' + window.location.hash.substr(1) + '"]').addClass("active");
    $("#" + window.location.hash.substr(1)).addClass("active");
  }

});
```

Comment: What should happen if the user comes back to your website another day? Should it remember which menu? or only when refreshing/reloading?

Comment: @NawedKhan in that scenario, the browser has been closed and not just refreshed, I would like menu-1/content-1 to be the default ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do it as following:

**1. Using #hash in URL:**
Every time the menu is clicked/changed set a hash in URL (for example www.yoursite.com#menu1). Then read the current hash every time you load the page and set the menu if there is a hash in URL.

Note: User will not see the previously selected menu if they close browser and come back later, or use a different machine. Only if the browser's Refresh was clicked (of F5 pressed) will the user see previously selected menu.

**2. Local Storage or cookie:**
Store and update the current selection in local storage or cookie. Then upon load read the Local Storage or Cookie to decide which menu to show. Local storage is in User's current browser and will stay there until you or the client deletes it. This means every time the user comes back they will see the previously selected menu.

Note 1: a cookie can be set to expire when browser closes so this way if the user close and open the browser they will not see the previously selected menu.

Note 2: If the user returns using a different machine or browser, they will not have the menu remembered.

**3. Server Side Storage:**
If you want to store the user's current state permanently and available across browsers and across machines then you should store the selection on server side (database or file).

Note: User has to be logged in for you to successfully identify them, may not be desirable.

So based on your question and comments Option number 1 is recommended. Or Option 2 with a cookie that expires with browser closing.

[Here is an article to nudge you in that direction.](https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/get-hash-value-from-url-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to save the selection in 
**local storage or session storage**
 and read it on browser reload. 
Since browser reload will re-render the app completely from first I don't think of any other option yet.

Comment: Or saving it to cookie :)